# How to package a local npm module?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I am trying to pack an npm package and install it on my webapp.

My application has the following structure:

- app

  - app.ts
  - app.css
- build

  - app.js
  - app.css
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
- .npmignore

I started with the [pack command](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/pack) documentation.

I added the .npmignore to include only the build folder.

As expected when running `npm pack`, I know have a new `app-1.0.0.tgz`

When I try to install it in the web app with `npm install ..\typescriptapp\typescriptapp-1.0.0`

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
>   npm ERR! Could not install from
>   "..\typescriptapp-1.0.0" as it does not contain a
>   package.json file.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>       C:\Users\corbin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-03-26T17_49_30_440Z-debug.log

However when I unzip the typescriptapp.tgz, I have the following structure

- typecriptapp-1.0.0

  - typecriptapp-1.0.0

    - package

      - build

        - app.js
        - app.css
      - package.json
      - tsconfig.json

Here is my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "typescriptapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "debug": "tsc -w"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/signalr": "2.2.35",
    "uglify-js": "3.3.16",
    "uglifycss": "0.0.28"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aspnet/signalr": "^1.0.0-preview1-update1",
    "lib": "file:../references/lib"
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your directory structure contains npm install ..\typescriptapp\typescriptapp-1.0.0\typescriptapp-1.0.0\package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to run install in the parent folder

```
npm install ..\typescriptapp\typescriptapp-1.0.0
```

Whereas you have to install it in

```
npm install ..\typescriptapp\typescriptapp-1.0.0\typescriptapp-1.0.0\package
```

Comment: You are right, i was missing the `.tgz ` to install the tarball properly. When unzipped, your solution work great, however, how should my local dependency be resolved. It currently tries to install from tarball location?

Comment: From local dependency, what do you wanna add

Comment: An external dependency which I added a package.json, currenly /references/whatIwant/package.json at the root of my projects. Idealy, it would be packed with my typescriptapp as a dependency.

I will keep looking thought I didn't look into this myself yet.

Comment: I think you can add up the dependencies in your package and it should work... But not sure about it will back to you if found something useful for you

Comment: Could not find anything posted a question a new https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49500192/how-to-bundle-dependencies-in-npm-package