# How to bundle dependencies in npm package?

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a npm package which reference an other local package. It has a structure like so.

- deploy

  - typescriptapp.tgz
- references

  - mydependency

    - package.json
    - app.js
    - app.css
- typescriptapp

  - package.json
- webapp

My typescriptapp package.json has the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "mydependency": "file:../references/mydependency"
  },
```

My webapp package.json has the following dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "typescriptapp": "file:../deploy/typescriptapp-1.0.0.tgz"
  },
```

When I use `npm pack` it work fine, but it is not included in the tarball. I also move the tarball to a deploy folder

When I try `npm install`, it doesn't work because the reference folder does not exist in the deploy folder.

I also tried to change the dependencies for bundledDependencies

```
  "bundledDependencies": [
    "file:../references/mydependency"
  ]
```

But it does not seem to work either.

How do I pack my typescript app to be able to install it in my webapp with a single file?